# Why isn't my String updating?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a small string variable with a  length of 400-500 characters spaces included.  I've tried a few things as far as removing some parts of the string, while in a Do/While loop.  I'm looking to go through the loop, then remove 300 characters from it, however it doesn't seem to be actually removing it from the string.

Are we not actually able to modify a string object and must be forced to SubString the text variable to get the desired result?

```
Do while stringText.Length >= 300
'stringText.replace(textToRemove, "") This doesn't replace the string variable
'stringText.Remove(0,299) This also doesn't remove the specified range of characters
Loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in .NET and VB are *[immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234766.aspx)*, meaning that a string can never change once it's been defined. What the various Replace/Remove methods do is return a *new*, modified string, which you can store to the same variable.

Like this:

```
Do while stringText.Length >= 300
   stringText = stringText.Replace(textToRemove, "") 
Loop
```

It's important to note, though, that this is potentially expensive - a new string object is allocated. If you have a lot of modifications to make to a string separately, each one will create a new copy, and for large strings it might create unnecessary memory allocations.

For this reason, we have the [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (as mentioned by roryap), which lets us manipulate strings directly. Read up on it.

Comment: Or better yet, use a `System.Text.StringBuilder`.

Comment: StringBuilder is overkill for a single string replace. Even in a loop, if there are only a handful of replacements.

Comment: Yeah, but it's certainly worth noting it in your answer and giving the appropriate context for its use.

Comment: The starting string could be thousands of characters in length, meaning thousands of strings will be created in memory -- one in each loop, and each one being approximately thousands of characters in length -- until the length falls below 300.  StringBuilder would be much better in that case.

Answer (score 2):

These functions return a value, you must assign the value returned to the original string for it to be updated:

e.g.

```
stringText = stringText.replace(textToRemove, "")
```

Otherwise you are just discarding the value returned - the functions do not mutate the original string

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign string for the return value

```
stringText =stringText.replace(textToRemove, "")
```